# Next.js How to make a redirect correctly

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have such a page structure.

```
locale can be any value from the language-country pair
eg en-ca, fr-fr, ar-en

[locale] // main folder route

   page1.tsx // child route

   page2.tsx // child route

   page3.tsx // child route
```

For example, if I go to the address **/page1**, then I redirect to **/locale/page1**

But the problem is that I check on the browser side and first a 404 page appears in the browser and only then redirects to the correct address.
I think that it is necessary to check on the server.
I was making my own file for the server. But the problem is that there is no way to track the address for which the request is going and that means I cannot check if the address starts with the parameter I need.

Comment: see: [Nextjs#Internationalized Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing)

Comment: no library i18n

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a specific reason why you're changing the `/pages` folder structure? Next.js already has built-in support for i18n routing.

Comment: i18n has file system system for translates. bad for me. need only api support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you do not wont to use Next.js native i18n routing you can create fallback page file `pages/[...fallback].ts` to catch all non-existing page. Then you can use use `getServerSideProps` to redirect properly.

This could work for you (not tested):

```
// The page content will never be rendered 
const FallbackPage = () => <div>Redirecting...</div>

// Is processed on every request on server side
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {

    // TODO: add custom detection (e.g. based on headers or cookies)
    const locale = 'en'
    const destination = `/${locale}/${ctx.params.fallback.join('/')}`

    return {
      props: {},
      redirect: { destination, permanent: false },
    }

}

export default FallbackPage
```